# CSS make a width:100% stop against floating objects

Tags: html, css

Try this:

```
<div style="float:left"><p>LEFT</p></div>
<div style="float:right"><p>RIGHT</p></div>
<div><p>
    <input type="text" style="width:100%" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <a href="">Link</a>
</p></div>
```

This ends up with LEFT and RIGHT being on the first line, the text input taking up the whole of the second line, and "Submit" and "Link" being on a third line.

I want **all of these to be on one line**, and if the window is widened, the text input should widen. How do I do this without tables?

Comment: Do you need that, specific markup? Would be easier if you could move the submit and the link to the right column.

Comment: For HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo or similar is a very useful thing to include with your question.

Comment: thirtydot IE7 is not required. @Yoshi the submit and link should be attached to the input, the three taken together should occupy a single line, being the maximal space between whatever else happens to be on the page.

Comment: I removed my "is IE7 required" comment because my answer mostly already works in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It can't be done without setting exact widths.**

Set exact width to left and right columns, also margin to center div. Here is my solution

## JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/xe4EJ/2/

## Code

```
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background-color:red"><p>LEFT</p></div>

<div style="float:right; width:200px; background-color:red"><p>RIGHT</p></div>

<div style="margin:0 210px 0 210px"><p>
    <input type="text" style="width:80%" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <a href="">Link</a>
</p></div>​
```

Comment: That results in the "Submit" and "link" being pushed down a line, so no good. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @spraff just decrease text-box size to 80% for example. See updated answer

Comment: No good, a solution involving magic numbers is simply not acceptable. It has to work regardless of the widths of the other elements (unless the screen is too narrow for all of them).

Comment: @spraff unfortunatelly you can't do it without setting exact width's

Answer (score 6):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/mSwBe/

This works in all modern browsers.

It's close enough on IE7 ([no support for `box-sizing: border-box`](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing), but this can be worked around easily enough, in this instance).

[`box-sizing: border-box`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/#box-sizing) makes the text `input` fit exactly inside the width of its containing `span`.

`overflow: hidden` is being [very useful](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats).

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="left"><p>LEFT</p></div>
<div id="right"><p>RIGHT</p></div>
<div id="middle">
    <span id="buttonContainer">
        <input type="submit" />
        <a href="">Link</a>
    </span>
    <span id="textContainer">
        <input type="text" />
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#left, #right, #middle {
    padding: 5px;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    background: #0ff;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    background: #0ff;
}
#middle {
    background: #f0f;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#middle input { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#textContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}
#textContainer input {
    width: 100%;
}
#buttonContainer {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: +1. The `overflow: hidden` did the trick for me. Thank you very much !

Comment: The `overflow:hidden` fixed a similar problem I was having. Never knew about this before. Thanks!

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to float everything to the left, and use some relative values on the div's.

```
<div style="float:left; margin-right: 20px; width: 20%;"><p>LEFT</p></div>
<div style="float:left;  margin-right: 20px; width: 20%;"><p>RIGHT</p></div>
<div style="float:left; margin-right: 20px; width: 50%;"><p>
    <input type="text" style="width:60%; " />
    <input type="submit" style="display:inline; width: 55px;" />
    <a href="">Link</a>
</p></div>​
```

You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/5k3m5/)

This WILL break when the page gets to a certain narrowness, so you might have to set a min-width on your body.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to float every element left and then you have to give every element a width:

```
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="float:left;width:10%"><p>LEFT</p></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:80%">
        <p style="clear:both">
            <input type="text" style="float:left;width:79%" />
            <input type="submit" style="float:left;width:10%" />
            <a href="" style="float:left;width:10%">Link</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;width:10%"><p>RIGHT</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach (building off oftrl13's solution) would be to isolate the text input in its own div and move the link and submit button to sit inside the static right-floated div:

```
<div style="float:left; width:200px; background-color:red"><p>LEFT</p></div>

<div style="float:right; width:300px; background-color:red">
    <input type="submit" />
    <a href="">Link</a>
   RIGHT</div>

<div style="margin:0 310px 0 210px"><p>
    <input type="text" style="float:left; width:100%; display:run-in;" />

</p></div>
```

[See it in at work](http://jsfiddle.net/bdappen/pU7Wp/1/)

​