# CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion

Tags: html, css

I have

```
body {
    background: url(images/background.svg);
}
```

The desired effect is that this background image will have width equal to that of the page, height changing to maintain the proportion. e.g. if the original image happens to be 100*200 (any units) and the body is 600px wide, the background image should end up being 1200px high. The height should change automatically if the window is resized. Is this possible?

At the moment, Firefox looks like it's making the height fit and then adjusting the width. Is this perhaps because the height is the longest dimension and it's trying to avoid cropping? I *want* to crop vertically, then scroll: no horizontal repeat.

Also, Chrome is placing the image in the centre, no repeat, even when `background-repeat:repeat` is given explicitly, which is the default anyway.

Comment: Does `html, body { height: 100%; }` help? Also, [*cough*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261894/css-make-a-width100-stop-against-floating-objects/9262586#comment11673092_9261894).

Comment: For anyone coming here trying to do this, you may also need to set `preserveAspectRatio: "none"` on your svg itself (edit its source). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658173/how-does-one-make-a-svg-background-that-stretches-rather-than-tiles

Answer (score 1001, accepted):

There is a CSS3 property for this, namely [`background-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/CR-css3-background-20110215/#the-background-size) ([compatibility check](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/)). While one can set length values, it's usually used with the special values `contain` and `cover`. In your specific case, you should use `cover`:

```css
body {
    background-image:    url(images/background.svg);
    background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;              /* optional, center the image */
}
```

### Eggsplanation for `contain` and `cover`

Sorry for the bad pun, but I'm going to use the [picture of the day by Biswarup Ganguly](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chicken_Egg_without_Eggshell_5859.jpg) for demonstration. Lets say that this is your screen, and the gray area is outside of your visible screen. For demonstration, I'm going to assume a 16x9 ratio.

[image: screen]

We want to use the aforementioned picture of the day as a background. However, we cropped the image to 4x3 for some reason. We could set the `background-size` property to some fixed length, but we will focus on `contain` and `cover`. Note that I also assume that we didn't mangle the width and/or height of `body`.

#### `contain`

> ```
> contain
> ```
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the background positioning area.

This makes sure that the background image is always completely contained in the background positioning area, however, there could be some empty space filled with your `background-color` in this case:

[image: contain]

#### `cover`

> ```
> cover
> ```
>
> Scale the image, while preserving its intrinsic aspect ratio (if any), to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can completely cover the background positioning area.

This makes sure that the background image is covering everything. There will be no visible  `background-color`, however depending on the screen's ratio a great part of your image could be cut off:

[image: cover]

#### Demonstration with actual code

```css
div > div {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5CAq.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
div.contain {
  background-size: contain;
}
div.cover {
  background-size: cover;
}
/********************************************
 Additional styles for the explanation boxes 
*********************************************/

div > div {
  margin: 0 1ex 1ex 0;
  float: left;
}
div + div {
  clear: both;
  border-top: 1px dashed silver;
  padding-top:1ex;
}
div > div::after {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fefefe;
  margin: 1ex;
  padding: 1ex;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
  width: 10ex;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="contain"></div>
  <p>Note the grey background. The image does not cover the whole region, but it's fully <em>contained</em>.
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="cover"></div>
  <p>Note the ducks/geese at the bottom of the image. Most of the water is cut, as well as a part of the sky. You don't see the complete image anymore, but neither do you see any background color; the image <em>covers</em> all of the <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thanks. It doesn't seem to work in Chrome (or Chromium, at least) -- got any bright ideas?

Comment: According to http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t44 it should work in Chrome without any prefix. However, have you tried the `-webkit-` prefix?

Comment: Yauhen's answer (at the bottom of this page) was actually what I was looking for: `background-size: contain`

Comment: @DannyBeckett: While this is possible, it isn't what the OP was looking for: *"I want to crop vertically, then scroll: no horizontal repeat."*

Comment: @DannyBeckett: The new revision should now cover all concerned problems. After all, my previous answer was rather minimal.

Comment: `contain` is like zoom fit. `cover` is like zoom fill.

`contain` adjusts image size to match the larger dimension among width and height. 

`cover` adjusts image size to match the smaller dimension among width and height.

Comment: @Zeta  sorry, my mistake, I confuse with the two border: blue and red border.

Answer (score 47):

Based on tips from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size I end up with the following recipe that worked for me

```
body {
        overflow-y: hidden ! important;
        overflow-x: hidden ! important;
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        background-image: url('index.png');
        /*background-size: cover;*/
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
}
```

Comment: Although I used `background-position: center;`, this did work better for me than `backgound-size: cover;`.

Comment: May I know why we need the `overflow-y: hidden` part?

Answer (score 28):

Background image is not Set Perfect then his css is problem create so his css file change to below code

```html
html {  
  background-image: url("example.png");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

%;  background-size: 100% 100%;"

Answer (score 14):

I'm not sure what you're looking for exactly, but you really should check out these excellent blog posts written by Chris Coyier from CSS-Tricks:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Read the descriptions for each of the articles and see if they're what you're looking for.

The first answers the following question:

> Is there a way to make a background image resizeable? As in, fill the background of a web page edge-to-edge with an image, no matter the size of the browser window. Also, have it resize larger or smaller as the browser window changes. Also, make sure it retains its ratio (doesn't stretch weird). Also, doesn't cause scrollbars, just cuts off vertically if it needs to. Also, comes in on the page as an inline  tag.

The second post's goal is to get the following, a "background image on a website that covers the entire browser window at all times. "

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Just add this one line:

```
    .your-class {
        height: 100vh;
    }
```

vh is viewport height.
This will automatically scale to fit the device' browser window.

Check more here: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window?rq=1)

Answer (score 9):

```
body{
    background-image: url(../url/imageName.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: describe what is the problem exactly and how you solve it, please don't paste a bunch of code here without explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
element.style {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/shopping_bgImg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, unable to resize the image when adjusting browser dimensions.

Bad Code:

```
html {  
  background-color: white;  
  background-image: url("example.png");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-attachment: scroll;  
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

Good Code:

```
html {  
  background-color: white;  
  background-image: url("example.png");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-attachment: scroll;  
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

The key here is the addition of this element -> *background-size: contain;*

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you set `min-height`, for example:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

You can use the below code to fit your background easily

```
body {
  background: url(images/background.svg);
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("../img/hero-bg.jpg") top center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

Use background-size cover property to fill the page. use background position, attachment, and repeat for background adjustments...

```css
html {
           background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2023/08/11/04/41/woman-8182795_1280.jpg);
           background-position: center center;
           background-attachment: fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
```

Answer (score -5):

Setting background size does not help, the following solution worked for me:

```
.class {
    background-image: url(blablabla.jpg);
    /* Add this */
    height: auto;
}
```

It basically crops the image and makes it fit in, `background-size: contain/cover` still didn't make it fit.