# Cover SVG Background by stretching

Tags: css, background, background-image

I would like to cover the entire width, but the image to be scaled to 70% of the  height.

```
<div class="Bg">Hello</div>
```

```
.Bg {
    background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/C_9.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So I would like the behaviour of `background-size: contain`, which stretches the image to the width of `background-size: cover`.

Codepen Example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOyYoR

Comment: Does `background-size: 100% 100%;` work for what you want?

Comment: not for my example, it centers the image, let me upload my image and change the codepen, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: I don't get what you need, can you show an image of what you have and what you want? contains just makes the image be 100% height or width depending on the ratios, and you say you want it to stretch to be 100% width, `100% 100%` does that.

Comment: Updated Codepen & the background image im trying to get working in the body of the text above ^

Comment: Ah, you are using an SVG, that's a different story.

Comment: You need to modify your SVG file to support stretching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658173/how-does-one-make-a-svg-background-that-stretches-rather-than-tiles

Comment: Read this too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Scaling_of_SVG_backgrounds