# Size Background Image to fit browser window JavaScript/HTML/CSS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I set the background image to fit the exact size of the browser's window. I am familiar with JavaScript/HTML/CSS/JQuery so any language will work for me.

Comment: Check out this http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Nelson 's comment I have found my answer here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

HTML & CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>bg</title>
<style>
.bg {
    background: url(yourimage);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Backstretch jQuery plugin for this before.

http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="images/BG.jpg" 

style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-5000;">
```

http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2010/10/css-making-background-image-fit-any.html