# Scale background image of div to a fixed width; auto-scale height

Tags: javascript, css

Similar to [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion), I want to scale an image to a fixed width, with an unlimited height.

Unlike that question though, this is for a `<div>`, not the `<body>`, which seems to introduce issues.

I've tried using the CSS3 property `background-size: cover`, but that shows 2 images like this (correct width but not tall enough):

> [image]

I've also tried using `background-size: contain`, but that shows like this (not wide enough, therefore not tall enough):

> [image]

I'm trying to get the images to look like this:

> [image]

Here's [**a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJAHz/) I've setup.

How can I get the `<div>`'s to be `171px` wide, but also auto-scale the height?

The dimensions of the images are not known. The images *must* come in the format `<div style="background-image: url('base64')">`, (not `<img src="base64">` - due to a restriction on the CLI program it is forwarded to) but I can modify any other HTML or CSS.

---

I have also tried using JavaScript to calculate what the height should be. That works good, but the `<div>`'s are not actually resized at the end:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = divs[i].style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2');
    var ratio = img.width / 171;
    var height = Math.floor(img.height / ratio);
    alert(height);
    divs[i].height = height;
}
```

Here's [an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJAHz/4/) with the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working with the JS option. I just needed to use `divs[i].style.height = height + 'px'` instead of `divs[i].height = height`:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = divs[i].style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2');
        var ratio = img.width / 171;
        var height = Math.floor(img.height / ratio);
        divs[i].style.height = height + 'px';
    }
}
```

Here's [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HaEWs/).

I'm still interested to know whether this is possible with pure CSS3 though. You'd think so!

---

I've further improved the code. Now, images that are smaller than `171px` wide are *not* stretched:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = divs[i].style.backgroundImage.replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2');

        if(img.width > 170)
        {
            var ratio = img.width / 171;
            var height = Math.floor(img.height / ratio);
        }

        else
        {
            var height = img.height;
            divs[i].style.backgroundSize = 'auto';
            divs[i].style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
        }

        divs[i].style.height = height + 'px';
    }
}
```

Here's the [final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UKDh4/).

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you can't add `<img src='base64'/>` inside the div elements then in the css have `div{background: 0px 0px}` to hide the div background and have `img{width:171px}`? See the modified [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Sdzz/). That solves the problem, but not sure if you are able to add the `img` tag. Let me know and i'll see if another solution can be found.

Comment: This is what I meant by "the images *must* come in that format". Unfortunately I have to use a `background-image`. The HTML file is sent to a command-line tool to convert it to PDF. It doesn't like `<img>`s unfortunately, and only works to use `background-image`s.

Comment: please clarify your question **before** down-voting, as that detail was not in the original post. thanks.

Comment: I already said this before. Check the last sentence of [revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17715201/revisions). Also, just to let you know, deleting your answer will actually *increase* your reputation, since it has a negative score.

Answer (score -1):

```
.divname img {
    height: auto;
    width: 171px;
```

}

And then for html do this:

```
    <div class="divname"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: I cannot use `<img>` tags for the reason explained on the other answer.

Comment: Then just add background-image: url(''); in front of the height and width