# CSS background image to fit height, width should auto-scale in proportion

Tags: css

I want background image fit with the height of the div, there's a way to do that? `background-size:cover;` fit only with the width and height autoscale (I need the opposite effect).
Thanks.

Comment: Try background-size: 1% 100%;

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
background-size: contain;
```

suits me

Comment: This doesn't work if your image is smaller than the container' height. @Ajikan answer below will work for that (```background-size: auto 100%;```)

Answer (score 137):

I know this is an old answer but for others searching for this; in your CSS try:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Comment: This is perfectly works for me. especially in my case when I want to have background image only resize based on the height alone.

Comment: This needs `min-height: 100%` to handle "taller than background" situations.

Comment: Very helpful! In my case I used the variation `background-size: auto auto;` so that whichever axis was smaller (width or height), it would stay within that. Otherwise it clipped when the page was resized.

Answer (score 14):

try

```
.something { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -100;  
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
body.bg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: white url(../images/bg-404.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}   
Try This


    body.bg {
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     min-height: 100vh;
     background: white url(http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-1920-1080-7.jpg) center center no-repeat;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
    } 
    <body class="bg">


     
    </body>
```

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same issue and this helped me:

```
html {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Other answers don't seem to correctly handle **both** "larger than background" and "taller than background" situations, or involve too much CSS.  This one works perfectly (BTW `height: auto;` isn't even needed, just use `background-size: cover; min-height: 100%`).

Comment: This is an amazingly simple answer for what seemed like a bug that I've been trying to solve on a site for weeks. I don't understand why `height` can't just be used like I was doing this whole time, but regardless, thank you. For the record, I found it was fine to set `background-size:cover` on the HTML element itself.

Answer (score -1):

This style helped me to fully fit image by height:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/static/img/grass.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100vh;    
}
```