# HTML and CSS background image scaling to fit screens

Tags: html, css, resize, background-image, scaling

I am currently working on building my portfolio website. I am using HTML and CSS. I have an image I am using for my background but the background remains the same size regardless of the size of the screen. What code should I use? Should I upgrade my code to CSS3/HTML5 and if so what would be the code for that? Thank you very much for your time and help ahead of time, this is a detail that is driving me nuts and a huge hang up when showing my work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Answer (score 3):

```
background-size : 100% auto
```

this gonna set width to 100% and height to auto

always search well before you post a question , this might be a good reference as a beginner :

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the code below:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: On Android it only worked for when using `html, body {...}` instead of `body {...}`.