# background-image url responsive image

Tags: html, image, css

I want to insert an image by CSS because I want to use captions over my image.

What I want is that the image shows completely and is responsive.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here you can see my HTML im using bootstrap. As you can see i want to let contentblock1 show an responsive image by using the CSS background-image code. I also want this background image to be responsive. But whatever i try it won't show me the background.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1> Dit is een bootstrap site</h1>
            <button type="button">click me!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="contentblock1">

            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using the following CSS

```
.contentblock1 {
background-image: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_zxdOSKs0ASI/TDMqbnatRwI/AAAAAAAAAkM/nB-DxcVcqqk/s1600/Testbeeld.jpg');
background-size: 100% 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion

Comment: Yeah i tried that but it doesnt work. When i give the html some breaks my image appears but thats not what i want

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nf1of39d/

Comment: Hi, The image is not scaling. I want the image to scale. Can you make a demo of that?

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100px; /*you width*/
height: 100px; /*you height*/
/* optional: background-color: white; */
background-image: url('image.png');
background-repeat: none;
background-size: 100% 100%;
/*or
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;*/
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Hi I tried ur code. But my image does not appear then.
.contentblock1 {
    background-image: url('http://freewallpaperspot.com/wallpapers/1024-768-3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
this is the code im using.

Comment: Changed the code with correct link. still not working.
.contentblock1 {
    background-image: url('http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_zxdOSKs0ASI/TDMqbnatRwI/AAAAAAAAAkM/nB-DxcVcqqk/s1600/Testbeeld.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

Comment: `.contentblock1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-image: url('http://freewallpaperspot.com/wallpapers/1024-768-3.jpg'); 
 background-size: cover; 
 background-position: 50% 50%; 
 background-attachment: fixed; 
}` missing size

Comment: The image does still not appear. I just want to insert an image by using the CSS image-background and that it is responsive. When i make <br> tags in my html then its beginning to show the image. But that aint right i think...

Comment: remove `background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;background-attachment: fixed;` and add `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: Is the image not showing because i dont got any text or content in it?
i tried ur code still it is not working. But thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: argues more about what you want to do **Edit your question** and use code

Comment: I changed my post for you. If you could take a look at it. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#some-div {
   background-image: <imgurl>;
   background-repeat: none; //Unless you want something else
   backgorund-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

and for responsiveness, use media-queries or a lib that is made for responsiveness such as Bootstrap.

Below you have an example of media-queries.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) 
{
   #some-div {
       width: 600px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{

   #some-div {
       width: 100%;
   }
}
```

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/e8xLf4u3/

Here is your working example, it only needed content. Also, in the future please show some code for faster help and better understanding

Graag gedaan ;)

Comment: I'm using bootstrap already. Can you give me the code perhaps?

Comment: Yea im using it. this is my html.
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1> Dit is een bootstrap site</h1>
                <button type="button">click me!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="contentblock1">
                    
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </body>

Comment: In your example, if you have added an img in your contentblock1:

CSS:

.contenblock1 img {
   width: 100%;
}

That should be enough.

Comment: I'm adding an image by using CSS. I aint using img src because i want to use captions.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You only need add background-size: 100% 100%; to your contentblock1, and also make your contentblock1 width: 100%.

Comment: I changed the code like you said. still the background does not display.

Comment: Can you post your code in the question, your HTML and your CSS?

Comment: Posted it with html and css.