# HTML DIV background

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>`  that includes a background image like this:

```
<div style="
  background: url('file://D:/DwyaneJohnsonBaller.jpg');
  width:100%; 
  height:1200px; 
  background-size: 100%;">
</div>
```

I've also tried to make the style of the `<div/>` in CSS format.

The problem I'm facing is that when I display the HTML file, I find some white spacing from top, right, left and bottom (i.e not fit with the whole web page).

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Comment: when width:100%, height should not be set in px. That is what creates the white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use - margin: 0;**

You can solve this by adding the following code to the **head** part of your html file:

```
<style>
  body{
  margin:0;
  }
</style>
```

Without this browser will display the content with blank spaces on all sides.

Answer (score 2):

To make backgound cover all of element, you should specify `background-size` as `cover`.

Previously on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265035/211131

Answer (score 2):

I sounds as though you need to remove the default margin from the body

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Try looking into "CSS Reset". There are several, just google that term.

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS file, you can input the following lines of code to make sure you get the right image, and also you can modify the size of the image to remove the white lines you are experiencing

```
body 
{
  background-image:url("otherimages/background.jpg");
  background-size:105%;
}
```

Also, since "background-size" is there, you don't need to have "width and height" parameters.
You can experiment with this, to make sure it works with your own project

Comment: why are you using a div to display a background image?

Comment: i will use this div afterwards to include buttons or labels at the end of the image, so i suggested that a div having a background image would be nice, and also i tried an img attribute

Comment: there is a problem google chrome leaves white spacing from the top,right,left and bottom of the image and i tried margin, padding background-size and all of these stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```