# Background image does not display the full height on mobile

Tags: html, css

A friend of mine has set up a little landing page and is asking me about an issue on mobile (Chrome). The background image (on the body) is set to cover

```
body {
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(14, 113, 184, 0.8) 0%, rgba(28, 22, 53, 0.6) 100%), url("../img/bgvid.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

The background image will render within the full viewport, but if I scroll down, it is kind of cut of, check the images down below to see what I mean (the gray block). He is asking for my help but I really don't know what could be causing this. I tried to remove the footer (and set the body height to 100%), but it did not change anything.

---

#### Solved

Fix: Looks like fixed background do not work on mobile browsers. This fixed it:

```
background-attachment: scroll;
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in the 2nd `row text-center` where the Sign Up Now button and the forms is inside. If you click on the button the problem seems to be temporary solved. So you may check these.

Answer (score 0):

[CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```