# is there any other way to fit the bg using html

Tags: html

I have an JPG image with size 1024 x 724. My page size is not fixed. My requirement is: If I resize the page then the background image should also resize and fit to the page.

Comment: refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: <html>
<body background="background.png">
</body>
</html>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image to fit width, height should auto-scale in proportion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this with backgroud-size  in css

If you'd like to use CSS3, you can do it pretty simply using background-size, like so:

```
background-size: 100%;
```

in you div you can add the style directly without using a css  external file

```
<div style ="background-size: 100%;" ....> .... </div>
```

Comment: i know it but i just want to know if there any other way using html ? 
like
body backgroung="png.png" height="100%" width ="100%"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a 100% width b aground which must cover up you complete background.
So please add this css in you style.css file.

```
html {
  background: url(yourimage.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  }
```