# Background Image not expanding with it's parent

Tags: css, image, sass, background-image, responsive-images

i am currently doing a challange on frontend mentor but i have a problem with the background images i used to create the curved sections, if you go to the developer's page, and expand the screen to let's say 2000px, the curved section do not expand

[A picture of what i am describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWUhF.png)

The code to the github repository is https://github.com/Nadine-Green/Huddle-Landing-Page-With-Curved-Sections, i was thinking of using it as a direct image instead of it being a background, but i just wanted to hear from you all first.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your GitHub repository and couldn't find the specific code referring to your attached screenshot containing curved background images.

Anyways [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262861/css-background-image-to-fit-width-height-should-auto-scale-in-proportion) it will help you take a better understanding of how to use background images properly on all screens (responsive).

If you are able to share the specific code snippet you are referring to with your question I would be able to help you further on.

Comment: thanks for the link, its really helpful, i will be sure to check it out.

Comment: @Liquorice My pleasure, also try https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ in your future projects it will help you build responsive web pages easily with fewer media queries. 
Mark my answer as correct ✔️ if you think it's the correct answer, or if it helped you please upvote ⬆️ it. Thanks in advance.