White space at the bottom and top of the background image
I want to make my background image responsive on mobile devices. Various problems arise when I change some properties in the css code. Either the image becomes responsive but it introduces a white space at the bottom and top of the image or else the image does not become responsive at all.
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('hand.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;

    }
</style>


Remove background-attachment: fixed;.

background-attachment: fixed does not work properly on IOS. Do you want the background to be fixed [to the viewport?].

@AHaworth i tried removing the background attachment but still not working. https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/robot-hand-side-view-background-presenting-technology-gesture_17850392.htm  This is the image that i am trying to apply on the webpage. When the photo viewed through a mobile it should scale down to fit the screen size

Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that background-attachment: fixed was the whole problem, but as a warning that it doesn't work on IOS properly. My question remains, do you want the background to be fixed [to the viewport]?

@AHaworth Yes I want it fixed to the viewport

this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265035/22343466

The requirement is to fill the viewport with the image, regardless of body's size.
Bearing in mind the IOS problem with background-attachment: fixed, this snippet instead puts the background on a pseudo element which is then fixed to the viewport so e.g. as you scroll it stays put.


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  body::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('https://i.sstatic.net/XWDio2gc.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>

<body>
  line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br></body>



